# How To Run A Complex .bat file

Tags: command-line, java, batch-file, minecraft

I am running a Minecraft server from Windows, and the .jar that starts the file is located at

```
C:\Users\David\Server\bin\pw\prok\KCauldron\1.7.10-1614.200\KCauldron-1.7.10-1614.200.jar
```

What I do to start the server now is as follows:

1. Open CMD
2. `cd` to `Users\David\Server\bin\pw\prok\KCauldron\1.7.10-1614.200`
3. Run `java -jar KCauldron-1.7.10-1614.200.jar`
4. The server runs, and outputs into CMD

What I would like to do is make a .bat file that will change a few things about how it will run.

1. <s>I would like to be able to double click a .bat file on my desktop to start the server</s>
2. **I would like the server to use the "minecraft sever" GUI, instead of outputting into CMD. EDIT: I feel as if I was unclear on what the "Default MC Server GUI" is. See the following picture:**

[image]
Now what's strange is that the way to get said default GUI is to double click the .jar file, however doing so with the KCauldron.jar file does not wield the same result. Any thoughts?

3. <s>I would like to allocate more RAM to my server, up to 7GB (7168 MB) But no less than 2 GB (2048 MB)</s>
4. <s>I want the server to auto save the log after it stops.</s>

If the GUI that the vanilla server runs can be used for KCauldron, please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following 3 lines in your bat file. Put your bat file on your desktop or wherever you want.

```
C:
cd "C:\Users\David\Server\bin\pw\prok\KCauldron\1.7.10-1614.200"
java -Xms2G -Xmx7G -jar KCauldron-1.7.10-1614.200.jar
```

This will do most of the things you asked. It will still output into a window, rather than "server GUI". This may be good enough for your purposes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you just need to folowing lines

1. @echo off
2. cd "C:\Users\David\Server\bin\pw\prok\kCauldron\1.7.10-1614.200
3. java -Xms2G -Xmx7G -jar KCauldron-1.7.10-1614.200.jar nogui

-
If you write nogui in the end, there will be not popup console, you can run commands in the command line

Comment: I want to use the default minecraft server GUI, see question for better detail.

Comment: Do not forget to change current drive to 'C:'. When the batch file starts, current drive is not necessarily C: (although if you store the batch file on the desktop, for most users it will be C:).

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)